# sizeof diferente en memoria dinámica C++

Tags: c++, array, matrices, memoria

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en C/C++ de forma autodidacta con ayuda de libros, vídeos y mucha práctica, aún soy todo un novato pero con muchas ganas de aprender.
Actualmente estoy trabajando con matrices dinámicas, y me surgió una duda respecto al tamaño que devuelve la función sizeof. Cuando uso sizeof en una matriz normal me devuelve correctamente el tamaño en bytes de la matriz (de toda la matriz, al menos que haga referencia a solo una fila, claro), y cuando uso sizeof en una matriz dinámica para saber su tamaño en bytes me devuelve siempre el mismo resultado - "4", o - "1", si hago referencia a una posición específica de la matriz.
Dejo los ejemplos para que se entienda:

**sizeof en una matriz estática (la salida del sizeof es 20)**

```
int main() {    

char matriz[5][4]{};
std::cout << "\nEl tamanio de la matriz estatica es: " << sizeof(matriz);

}
```

**sizeof en una matriz dinámica (la salida del sizeof es 4)**

```
int main() {

char** matriz;
matriz = new char* [5]{};
for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    matriz[x] = new char[5]{};
}
std::cout << "\nEl tamanio de la matriz dinamica es de: " << sizeof(matriz);

}
```

Por que es que cuando uso una matriz estática (que se guarda en la pila) el tamaño que me devuelve la función sizeof() es 20, y cuando uso una matríz dinámica, el tamaño que me devuelve la función sizeof() es 4?, hay forma de mostrar el tamaño total de una matriz dinámica, tal y como lo hice con la matriz estática?.

Comment: Te da ese resultado en el segundo `sizeof` porque `matriz` es un puntero y está devolviendo el tamaño en bytes que ocupa el *puntero*. En este caso, es `4` bytes, aunque esto dependerá si la máquina es de 32 ó 64 bits.

Answer (score 1):

En pocas palabras, `sizeof` es un operador que se aplica en tiempo de compilación.  En el caso del *array*/matriz/arreglo, se conoce su tamaño, y en el caso del array dinámico, `sizeof` se refiere a un puntero a caracter(es), que dependiendo de la arquitectura, te dará un tamaño que depende de tal arquitectura.

Puedes ver esto y más en esta documentación de C++ en español:
[operador sizeof](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof)

Answer (score 1):

Aquí tienes la explicación del sizeof: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof

A ver en tu caso con memoria estática el compilador conoce el tamaño de tu matriz, ya que este tamaño se define en tiempo de compilación en la zona de datos, sin embargo en el caso de memoria dinámica, matriz es un puntero, por ello su tamaño devuelto en sizeof es 4 (presumo que estás usando un compilador de 32 bits, que es el tamaño de un puntero en arquitecturas de ese tipo, así sizeof devuelve el tamaño en bytes, luego son 4*8 = 32 bits), por ello al operar el size of sobre **matriz, es un puntero por eso te devuelve el tamaño de 4.

Realmente cuando usas memoria dinámica la estás alocando en el heap, y el compilador no reserva esa memoria (en el caso de matriz[5][4], ahí sí la está reservando en tiempo de compilación), sino que lo haces tú al hacer el new.

Es por eso que el compilador no conoce el tamaño de la memoria que tú reservas en el heap, sin embargo sí lo conoce en el caso de la memoria que se reserva en el stack ya que él mismo la está reservando. Por eso en memoria dinámica tú mismo debes llevar la cuenta de lo que reservas.

He intentado explicarlo lo más simple posible, pero te recomiendo que intentes entender el tratamiento de punteros, busca información sobre eso.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas almacenar el número de elemento de alguna forma.

```
  char** matriz;
  const int elementos = 5;
  matriz = new char* [elementos]{};
  for (int x = 0; x < elementos; x++) 
  {
      matriz[x] = new char[elementos]{};
  }

  std::cout << "\nEl tamanio de la matriz dinamica es de: " << sizeof(char*) * elementos;
```

Puedes verificarlo [aquí](https://rextester.com/MMDJ40069).

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` es una función que se evalúa en tiempo de compilación, es decir, el valor que devuelve se calcula mientras se está compilando el programa y dicho valor no va a cambiar de ninguna forma.

**Arrays**

```
int main() {    
    char matriz[5][4]{};
    std::cout << sizeof(matriz);
}
```

Los arrays tienen ciertas características que los diferencian de los punteros:

- Se alojan en la pila del programa
- Su tamaño es fijo y no se puede modificar
- Decaen a puntero, es decir, se pueden convertir implícitamente en punteros

Un array tiene un tamaño equivalente al número de elementos que contiene multiplicado por el tamaño de cada elemento, y este es el valor que devuelve `sizeof`

**Punteros**

```
int main() {
    char** matriz = new char* [5]{};
    std::cout << sizeof(matriz);
}
```

Los punteros son variables que almacenan direcciones de memoria, es decir, el tamaño de un puntero será **siempre** el mismo que el tamaño de las direcciones de memoria:

- 32 bits en equipos de 32 bits
- 64 bits en equipos de 64 bits

Pues bien, ese será el valor que devuelva el operador `sizeof`.

**Objetos**

```
struct POO
{
  int valor1;
  float valor2;
};

int main() {    
    POO p;
    std::cout << sizeof(p);
}
```

Los objetos instanciados por valor, sin usar el operador `new`, se alojan en la pila del programa. Aquí nos encontramos con un caso similar al de los arrays, es decir, usar `sizeof` con un objeto de este tipo nos devolverá lo que ocupa el objeto instanciado en memoria.

Sin embargo, si usamos un puntero, obtendremos un resultado diferente y esto es, como hemos explicado antes, porque los punteros son variables que almacenan direcciones de memoria, y `sizeof`, en este caso, lo que evalúa es lo que ocupa la variable en cuestión en memoria:

```
int main() {    
    POO obj;
    POO * ptr1 = null;
    POO * ptr2 = &obj;
    std::cout << sizeof(obj) << '\n'
              << sizeof(ptr1) << '\n'
              << sizeof(ptr2) << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto lo probe con una matriz estatica pero tale vez sirva en una matriz dinamica
se tiene un matriz como la siguiente:

```
int array[] = {10,20,30,40};
```

Y como se obtiene la cantidad de datos es la sig:

```
int n = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
```

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/328299)